# Windows Anytime Upgrade license key not working

Tags: windows-7, anytime-upgrade

I have Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit on my Sony Vaio laptop. It came installed on the laptop, I have not reinstalled or done anything else to it.

I have just tried to upgrade to Ultimate via the Anytime Upgrade tool. I followed the prompts and purchsed the online license key for Ultimate, but now when I try to apply the upgrade, I get an error:

> Enter a different upgrade key. The upgrade key you entered is for an edition of Windows that does not work with Windows Anytime Upgrade.

What have I done wrong? All I did was follow the prompts from within Windows itself. I am in the UK, the laptop was bought directly from Sony in the UK, so as far as I can tell I am definitely eligible for online purchase of an Anytime Upgrade license key.

Comment: Why don't you ask to MS support people?

Comment: Because then the question and its answer wouldn't be here on SuperUser for other people to refer to.

Comment: Are you sure you transposed the key properly? When you followed the prompts, are you sure you weren't led away from the Anytime Upgrade section? Have you tried anything (say, from any of the dozens of answers on answers.microsoft.com, or www.windows7.com/getkeysupport)?

Comment: @GrahamBorland That other people should refer to MS support, too. So my comment is really my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the upgrade to Ultimate seems to have actually worked, which is why Anytime Upgrade complains that my license isn't valid for further upgrades.

I don't know why the initial upgrade reported a failure, but anyway it all seems to be working fine now.

Comment: I experienced the same issue a while back.  If I had just rebooted, I probably could have saved something like 3 hours of support time with Microsoft.